# why i am getting this number?

Tags: c++, arrays

i am trying to merge two arrays into one. but could not figure out why the number comes out instead of the desired number and what does this number signify.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void MergeArray(int[], int, int[], int,int[]);

void main()
{
    int A[50], m, B[50], n, C[100],a, mn;

    cout<<"Enter the size of First Array::\n";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"Enter the First Array(ASCENDING ORDER)\n";
    for(int i=0; i<m ; i++)
        cin>>A[i];

    cout<<"Enter the size of Second Array::\n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter the Second Array(DESCENDING ORDER) ::\n";
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        cin>>B[j];

    mn=m+n;
    MergeArray(A,m,B,n,C);

    cout<<"The Array After merging is ::\n";
    for(int k=0; k < mn; k++ )
        cout<<C[k]<<"\n";
    cout<<"Press any key";
    cin>>a;

}


void MergeArray(int a[],int M , int b[], int N, int c[] )
{
    int x,y,z;
    z=0;

    for(x=0, y=N-1; x<M && y>=0;)
    {
        if(a[x]<=b[y])
            c[z++]=a[x++];

        else if(b[y]<a[x])
            c[z++]=b[y--];
    }

    if(x<M)
    {
        while(x<M)
            c[z++]=a[x++];
    }

    if(y>0)
    {
        while(y>=0)
            c[z++]=b[y++];

    }

    getch();

}
```

[image: Image of the output screen]}

Comment: sorry for that i just found out the right place for my question

Comment: Shouldn't `if(y>0)` be `if(y>=0)`, and `y++` be `y--` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is right here:

```
if(y>0)
{
    while(y>=0)
        c[z++]=b[y++];  // <-- y++ instead of y--

}
```

You should be decreasing `y`, not increasing it.

Answer (score 0):

You see this strange number because you printing non-initialized item of array.
You don't process last element from second array here. Also you use increment for `y` but you should use decrement.
Instead of

```
if(y>0)
{
    while(y>=0)
        c[z++]=b[y++];

}
```

You should use

```
if(y>=0)
    {
        while(y>=0)
            c[z++]=b[y--];

    }
```